# Which exception should I expect

Tags: java, spring, testing, datasource

There is a unit test that violates database unique constraint. When I run:

```
try {
    someDao.save(employee2);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Class clazz = e.getClass();
    System.out.println( clazz.getName());
}
```

The actual class of `e` is `javax.persistence.PersistenceException`.
Ok, I update the test code to:

```
exception.expect(PersistenceException.class);
someDao.save(employee2);
```

But the test fails with the following error:

```
Expected: an instance of javax.persistence.PersistenceException
     but: <org.junit.internal.runners.model.MultipleFailureException: There were 2 errors:
  javax.persistence.PersistenceException(org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement)
  org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException(Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly)> is a org.junit.internal.runners.model.MultipleFailureException
Stacktrace was: org.junit.internal.runners.model.MultipleFailureException: There were 2 errors:
  javax.persistence.PersistenceException(org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement)
  org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException(Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly)
```

I've tried all the following exceptions, but it did not help:

```
exception.expect(org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException.class);
exception.expect(org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException.class);
```

Which exception should I expect when a database constraint is violated?

Comment: can `expect` take a list or a variable length argument? Then you would give both exceptions to the same call of `expect`. Alternatively (which would be admittedly ugly), you could expect the `MultipleFailureException`.

Comment: try asserting this on the getCause() method of the caught exception - PersistenceException may be wrapping the ConstraintViolationException

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way but will work good for unit testing!

```
    try 
  {
    someDao.save(employee2);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
```

Lets say you get some output.Lets store it in **Error** String. Note this down and update your test case as follows

```
@Test
public void testException() {
    try {
       someDao.save(employee2);
       fail("expected an exception");
    } catch (PersistenceException ex) {
       assertEquals(Error, ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the JPA vendor adapter ([setJpaVendorAdapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.html#setJpaVendorAdapter%28org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter%29))
on your entity manager? Without that, Spring won't interpret the Hibernate specific exception so instead throws generic ones.

Answer (score 0):

The hierarchy of Exceptions is:
TransactionSystemException 
getCause() -> RollBackException
getCause() -> ConstraintViolationException

So you could try:

```
    try {
        taskRepository.save(task);
    } catch (TransactionSystemException e) {
        assertThat("name must not be null", e.getCause().getCause(), instanceOf(ConstraintViolationException.class));
    }
```

That doesn't guarantee which constraint is failing but given the scope of the test it might be enough.  You would have to delve deep into the constraint error to get more specific details